# Left Join Multiple Tables on one master table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am referring to sqlzoo joining exercise linked here:
https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

I already solved it using 'CASE WHEN' as requested in the question, but I am just trying to do it in a different way.

below is my code which gave me the right answer in all columns except score2 column, it's showing the same result as score1, I was just wondering what mistake I did in the below code.

[These are the given tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ0mf.jpg)

[This is the target result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dxwu.jpg)

```
 SELECT 
  MDATE, 
  TEAM1, 
  COUNT(X.MATCHID) AS SCORE1,
  TEAM2,
  COUNT(Y.MATCHID) AS SCORE2 
FROM GAME
LEFT JOIN GOAL X ON ID = X.MATCHID AND TEAM1 = X.TEAMID
LEFT JOIN GOAL Y ON ID = Y.MATCHID AND TEAM2 = Y.TEAMID
GROUP BY MDATE, TEAM1, TEAM2
```

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you here.

Comment: I also strongly recommend you alias all your table's, and qualify all your columns; what table is `ID` coming from, for example?

Comment: Your question should be self-contained, not relying on external links; as pointed out you need to be aliasing all tables and columns so it's easily readable with no ambiguity; I'd probably use a correlated sub-query here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `COUNT` works.

It counts all non-null values passed to it. And it does not count the number of `MATCHID` in each table before the join, it only works after the join.

So the final resultset *after* joining is then fed into the `GROUP BY`, and only then is `COUNT` executed. Since `MATCHID` is non-null, the same result comes out for both counts.

Instead you need to pre-group, either using `LEFT JOIN` or `APPLY`

```sql
SELECT 
  GAME.MDATE, 
  GAME.TEAM1, 
  G1.SCORE1,
  GAME.TEAM2,
  G2.SCORE2 
FROM GAME
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MATCHID, TEAMID, COUNT(*) SCORE1
    FROM GOAL
    GROUP BY MATCHID, TEAMID
) G1 ON GAME.ID = G1.MATCHID AND GAME.TEAM1 = G1.TEAMID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MATCHID, TEAMID, COUNT(*) SCORE2
    FROM GOAL
    GROUP BY MATCHID, TEAMID
) G2 ON GAME.ID = G2.MATCHID AND GAME.TEAM2 = G2.TEAMID;
```

Alternately

```sql
SELECT 
  GAME.MDATE, 
  GAME.TEAM1, 
  G1.SCORE1,
  GAME.TEAM2,
  G2.SCORE2 
FROM GAME
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) SCORE1
    FROM GOAL G1
    WHERE GAME.ID = G1.MATCHID AND GAME.TEAM1 = G1.TEAMID
) G1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) SCORE2
    FROM GOAL G2
    WHERE GAME.ID = G2.MATCHID AND GAME.TEAM2 = G2.TEAMID
) G2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH xGoalQ
AS
(
    SELECT MATCHID, TEAMID , COUNT(1) AS Score
    FROM GOAL
    GROUP BY MATCHID, TEAMID
)

SELECT 
  MDATE, 
  TEAM1, 
  X.Score AS SCORE1,
  TEAM2,
  Y.Score AS SCORE2 
FROM GAME
LEFT JOIN xGoalQ X ON ID = X.MATCHID AND TEAM1 = X.TEAMID
LEFT JOIN xGoalQ Y ON ID = Y.MATCHID AND TEAM2 = Y.TEAMID
ORDER BY MDATE, TEAM1, TEAM2
```

OR

```
SELECT 
  MDATE, 
  TEAM1, 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM GOAL WHERE MATCHID = GAME.Id AND TEAMID = GAME.Team1) AS SCORE1,
  TEAM2,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM GOAL WHERE MATCHID = GAME.Id AND TEAMID = GAME.Team2) AS SCORE2 
FROM GAME
ORDER BY MDATE, TEAM1, TEAM2
```